# Get size of a object from a PDF file

Tags: c#, pdf, pdfsharp

I need to save a chart from Microsoft Excel as a PDF file. (Save As -> File Type: PDF) This will produce a sigle page PDF file where the chart is always located in the middle and also the chart is scaled to fit the page width.

The result is fine but the chart can get lots of extra white space around it that I'd like to get rid of. I'm using **PdfSharp** to manipulate with the PDF file but I'm unable to find the chart (object) inside the PDF and **calculate the actual size**.

I know that Aspose.PDF library has a function for it - [CalculateContentBBox](https://apireference.aspose.com/net/pdf/aspose.pdf/page/methods/calculatecontentbbox) but I cannot use the library in my project.

Is there anyway how to get the same or similar via PdfSharp?
I believe the chart is stored as

```
'/Contents'
```

in the internal structure

Here is what I have tried so far (An example PDF file is included on GitHub)
Thanks

https://github.com/PetLahev/PdfSharpQuestion

```
using System;
using System.Reflection;
using System.IO;
using PdfSharp.Pdf;
using PdfSharp.Pdf.IO;
using PdfSharp.Pdf.Advanced;

namespace PDFSharpProject
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Provide path to a PDF file (or just hit enter to get the default)");
            string path = Console.ReadLine();
            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(path))
            {
                path = Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location), "TestPDF.pdf");
            }

            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(path)) return;
            TryToFindObject(path);
        }

        private static void TryToFindObject(string pdfPath)
        {
            PdfDocument pdf = PdfReader.Open(pdfPath);
            PdfPage page = pdf.Pages[0];
            PdfDictionary contents = page.Elements.GetDictionary("/Contents");
            if (contents == null) return;

            var items = contents.Elements.Values;
            Console.WriteLine("Here I don't know what to do");

        }
    }
}
```

So I'd like to get the content in the red 'rectangle' (*of course this should be real rectangle*). Mainly I need to get rid of the left/right white space. I can handle top/bottom
[image]

Comment: How *do* you "handle top/bottom", then? Why does it not work for left/right as well?

Comment: I almost  hardcoded it. The charts I'm working with are pretty standard in term of height but the width vary. Depends of many parameters like if it has two axis, the number format, the size of font, if the user changes the plot area manually by dragging it by mouse etc. I'm just hoping the PdfSharp has similar functionality like Aspose.PDF which is working pretty fine in the trial version I could test

Comment: FYI: Inspecting the file with Acrobat, I see that there is an amount of unused space around the figure (which, I presume, can trivially be cropped), but there is also a clipping mask that expands beyond your free-hand rectangle. Technically, that mask "is" the limit of what you can reasonably crop automatically. To go beyond that, you'd need a per-object test. (Not that I know how to crop to that mask to begin with.)

Comment: Ah – you can use that other library and see if it does accurately calculate the actual visible objects' boundaries, or stops at that wider clipping mask. Run it and check if the resulting bounding box is very close to the visible items. That'll give you something to aim for.

Comment: @usr2564301 When you are saying "Inspecting the file" how did you find out? I was trying one tool which name I don't remember now, something O2 I think, and now I'm checking via 'CosEdit' but for me all the information I can see there is just one big mystery.